# Deserialize array with Borsh in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to deserialize an array:

```rust
pixels: [(Pubkey, u8); 1_000 * 1_000],
```

I've added the following crate attribute:

```
#![feature(trivial_bounds)]
```

Here's the compile error:

```
   |
76 | #[account]
   | ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `BorshSerialize` is not implemented for `[(anchor_lang::prelude::Pubkey, u8); 1000000]`
   | 
  ::: /home/vedantroy/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/borsh-0.9.1/src/ser/mod.rs:44:18
   |
44 |     fn serialize<W: Write>(&self, writer: &mut W) -> Result<()>;
   |                  - required by this bound in `anchor_lang::AnchorSerialize::serialize`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <[T; 0] as BorshSerialize>
             <[T; 1024] as BorshSerialize>
             <[T; 10] as BorshSerialize>
             <[T; 11] as BorshSerialize>
           and 37 others
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `BorshSerialize` for `GameState`
   = note: this error originates in an attribute macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0277]: the trait bound `[(anchor_lang::prelude::Pubkey, u8); 1000000]: BorshDeserialize` is not satisfied
  --> programs/auction/src/lib.rs:76:1
   |
76 | #[account]
   | ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `BorshDeserialize` is not implemented for `[(anchor_lang::prelude::Pubkey, u8); 1000000]`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <[T; 0] as BorshDeserialize>
             <[T; 1024] as BorshDeserialize>
             <[T; 10] as BorshDeserialize>
             <[T; 11] as BorshDeserialize>
           and 36 others
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `BorshDeserialize` for `GameState`
   = note: required by `anchor_lang::AnchorDeserialize::deserialize`
   = note: this error originates in an attribute macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `auction`
```

Is it possible to deserialize an array with Borsh?

Comment: Could you please include some minimal code to reproduce the error? This is hard to answer with the information given.

Answer (score 0):

On older versions of Rust `BorshSerialize` / `BorshDeserialize` are implemented for a variety of array sizes, but not all (this would require const generics). This has since been stabilized, but I guess they didn't want to bump the minimum requires Rust version.

If you specify the `const-generics` feature in your Cargo.toml this should work though:

```
borsh = { version = "0.9", features = ["const-generics"] }
```

That said, having a very large array like that will generally blow up in your face through stack overflows, so I would recommend turning it into a `Vec<(PubKey, u8)>` instead.